# D3.js Barchart: getting x-axis labels to line up with bars, and rotate them slightly

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

I've got a d3 vertical bar chart, and I'm trying to get the x-axis labels positioned appropriately.  It's *almost* there, but not quite.  The labels end up being off-center from the bars.  I'd also like to rotate the labels slightly, so that I can accommodate a larger graph when I need to.

Here's my coffee for the chart (there's some Backbone Marionette in there):

```
  buildTimeline: ->
    width = @ui.chartWrap.innerWidth()
    height = @ui.chartWrap.height()
    dataLength = @data.values.length

    x = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1)
    y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0])
    x.domain @data.values.map (d) ->
      d.x
    y.domain [0, d3.max(@data.values, (d) ->
      d.y
    )]
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")

    svg = d3.select(@ui.chartWrap[0]).append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', '0,0')

    svg.append("g")
      .attr('id', 'timeline-labels')
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,#{height-20})")
      .call(xAxis)

    # Bars
    svg.append('g')
      .attr('id', 'timeline-bars')
      .selectAll(".bar")
      .data(@data.values)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", (d) ->
        x(d.x)
      )
      .attr("width", 25)
      .attr("y", (d) ->
        y(d.y) - 30
      )
      .attr("height", (d) =>
        height - y(d.y)
      ).attr("data-date", (d) =>
        d.x
      ).attr("data-count", (d) =>
        d.y
      )
```

And then here's my sample JSON for the graph:

```
{
    "key": "Documents",
    "values": [
        {
            "x": "1980",
            "y": 1752
        },
        {
            "x": "1981",
            "y": 0
        },
        {
            "x": "1982",
            "y": 0
        },
        {
            "x": "1983",
            "y": 0
        },
        {
            "x": "1984",
            "y": 0
        },
        {
            "x": "1985",
            "y": 0
        },
    ],
    "type": "year"
}
```

The final chart was nearly there, but now all the labels are stacking up under one bar:[image: D3 Chart]

Comment: Any reason you're not using the axis you're creating? `svg.append("g").call(xAxis)` (with some translation) should take care of the positioning of the labels.

Comment: Honestly I inherited this code, and I'm pretty new to d3.  How can I utilize the xAxis?

Comment: Like I've outlined above. You append a `g` element and then `.call(xAxis)`.

Comment: Adding `svg.append('g').call(xAxis)` creates a `g` within the canvas that has the `domain` class and a `d` attribute, but no values.  All it does is produce a weird black bar across the top of my chart: http://cl.ly/image/1O040U1T0l0L

Comment: Yep, you'll have to do some styling etc. See e.g. [this tutorial](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/axes).

Comment: Looks like there's a problem in my `xAxis` or scale somewhere. It's drawing in all the ticks, but they are stacking at 0, instead of spreading out beneath the bars. http://cl.ly/image/3G192n0v3U13

Comment: Are you drawing the axis before you've set the domain of the scale?

Comment: I was, but I've updated the code in my example to reflect what I'm using now.

Comment: You should parse the dates as such and use a time scale. See for example http://jsfiddle.net/robdodson/KWRxW/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @lars-kothoff.  Solution ultimately turned out to be using a time scale:

```
  buildTimeline: ->
    width = @ui.chartWrap.innerWidth()
    height = @ui.chartWrap.height()
    dataLength = @data.values.length
    x = d3.time.scale()
      .domain(
        [
          new Date "#{@data.values[0].x}-1-1"
          new Date("#{@data.values[dataLength - 1].x}-1-1")
        ]
      ).rangeRound [0, width]

    y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain(
        [
          0
          d3.max(@data.values, (d) ->
            d.y
          )
        ]
      ).range [height, 0]

    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient('bottom')
      .ticks(d3.time.years, 1)
      .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%Y'))
      .tickSize(0)
      .tickPadding(8)

    yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient('left')
      .tickPadding(8)

    svg = d3.select(@ui.chartWrap[0]).append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', '0,0')

    # Bars
    svg.append('g')
      .attr('id', 'timeline-bars')
      .selectAll(".bar")
      .data(@data.values)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", (d) ->
        x(new Date "#{d.x}-1-1")
      )
      .attr("width", 25)
      .attr("y", (d) ->
        y(d.y) - 30
      )
      .attr("height", (d) =>
        height - y(d.y)
      ).attr("data-date", (d) =>
        d.x
      ).attr("data-count", (d) =>
        d.y
      )

    svg.append("g")
      .attr('id', 'timeline-labels')
      .attr('class', 'x axis')
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,#{height-20})")
      .call(xAxis)

    svg.append("g")
      .attr('class', 'y axis')
      .call(yAxis)
```